# Use of the て form in a sentence like this

Tags: て-form, reading-comprehension

> いい成績を取れば褒められたし、交友関係に煩く口出しもしなかったし、漫画やゲームといった娯楽を無駄だと言って一切封じられていたわけでもない。

> 、漫画やゲームといった娯楽を無駄だと言って一切封じられていた

Specially concerning this line.

Does it imply they  called these things 無駄 but they didn't forbid them it OR is it that didn't call them 無駄 and neither did forbid them?

Essentially is the わけでもない。 acting for と言って too?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the わけでもない here applies to both 娯楽を無駄だと言って and 一切封じられていた.

I don't know the grammatical mechanisms behind it well enough to give you an argument as to why using that sort of information, but if you look for translated example sentences that also have that construction, all of them include the clause with て as being included in わけでもない

For example, from [here](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-japanese-grammar-n2-%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/). I've omitted surrounding information to make it easier to read. Roughly corresponding parts are bolded.

[] **アメリカを追って**底辺に駆け込もうとしているわけではない。
[] are not **racing young Americans** to the bottom.

[] わたしは**心から楽しんで**英語を勉強していたわけではありません。
[] I didn’t **truly enjoy** studying English at first.

Also note that in the second sentence the part with 〜て is necessary for わけではない. 英語を勉強していたわけではありません would be a false statement

That's not to say that 〜て〜わけでもない or わけではない never excludes the 〜て in わけでもない, but it certainly is a possibility that it includes it. There are certain scenarios where it is excluded more than included.

When you look at situations in which 〜て isn't included specifically for 言って, it seems to mostly be when the statement before 言って is opposing the statement after it from the point of view of the speaker in one of two constructions. I used Google search tools to check for sentences containing "と言って*わけでもない." There are several categories to those: those that are と言っているわけでもない (accidental results), those that contain かと言って or からと言って, and those that contain だと言って, [adjective]と言って, or [verb]と言って. I then searched for each individually, with the main considerations here being that Google refuses to show all of the results it display as existing, and therefore the sample size is low. (And also that there's no easy way to search for [adjective]と言って, or [verb]と言って)

かと言って and からと言って are often listed as grammar points in their own right and both generally indicate that the clause before them opposes the clause after in a sort of "even if this is is the case" way. Listed below are some examples with loose translations I've provided that I think can be assumed to be so from context.

からと言って
**遅いからと言って**悪いわけでもない ([source](https://taesunworld.com/post_lp/aim/))
**Just because (you)'re slow** doesn't mean that's a bad thing.

**失禁したからと言って**死ぬわけでもない ([source](https://ameblo.jp/narachaaan/entry-12794331645.html))
You're not going to die **from being incontinent.**

Note: neither of these appear on the actual websites but do appear in the previews for whatever reason
かと言って
ちゃんと重量感もあり、**かと言って重いわけでもない** ([source](https://www.amalgamated-bronx.coop/item/m644204310))
It has a good feeling of weight to it, **but despite that it's not heavy**

薄めた醤油で蕎麦をすすってる感じ**かと言ってまずいわけでもない** ([source](https://%20%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A4%E3%82%B7%20%E7%A8%AE%2010%E5%80%8B%20%E3%83%A4%E3%82%B7%20%7C%20basz-arq.com%20%20basz-arq.com%20https://basz-arq.com%20%E2%80%BA%20...))
It's like slurping soba through thinned shoyu, **but that's not to say it's bad**

だと言って (only contained one result)
キレイだと言って欲しいわけでもないんですね ([source](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1369670408))

It does appear almost like the speaker is saying "just because someone is pretty doesn't mean they're wanted," but within the context of the post (she is referring to literally being told she is pretty) + the use of だと言って and not かと言って or からと言って, it seems like it's actually "it's not like you call me pretty and you want me." The fact that she was called pretty is known, so the わけでもない has to not apply to キレイだと言って. However, following the logic of the first examples, in a different context it should also be able to apply to both statements. I think it can't be determined whether or not キレイだと言う is something that actually happened without more information.

To summarize this unnecessarily longwinded answer, 漫画やゲームといった娯楽を無駄だと言って封じられていた as a whole (the saying AND the preventing put together) 100% did not happen, but the sentence doesn't have any concrete information on whether or not 漫画やゲームといった娯楽を無駄だと言って happened or not.